# how to flush or clear GetAsyncKeyState's buffer

Tags: c++, mfc

i'm using `GetAsyncKeyState` in an MFC application to check if Esc button is pressed,
but when i press on Esc button from dialog and use `GetAsyncKeyState` in a different dialog it returns nonzero because it's exists in the message queue.

how can i clear or flush `GetAsyncKeyState`'s buffer or delete this message from message queue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `GetKeyState` does what you require, source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation you can read:

> ***If the most significant bit is set, the key is down***, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

(emphasis mine)

so to check current state of ESC button you should only check most significant bit:

```
bool isEscPressed = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000;
```

if you check state like that: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {}` then it will enter `if` statement even if ESC is not currently pressed.

Comment: i'm using `GetAsyncKeyState`  inside a function that takes a lot of time and when i use
    (GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000) 
it didn't work @Marcin Jędrzejewski

Comment: @AmirYouhana then dont use GetKeyState but GetAsyncKeyState,

Comment: @AmirYouhana sorry I by mistake used GetKeyState in my answer instead of GetAsyncKeyState

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question would be just calling it a second time, discarding the value from the first time.

But I guess that what you *really* want to know is how to read the *current* status of the key, regardless of when you last checked. Since you wrote "returns nonzero" I believe you are not using it correctly.

You need to check for the bit with value 0x8000 because this one indicates whether it's pressed *right now*. The bit with the value 1 is the one which is set if the key was pressed since the last check, and that's the one tripping you over, so just ignore it and directly test for the bit with value 0x8000.

Example code:

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000) yayReturnIsPressed();
```

Checking `if(GetKeyState(VK_RETURN))` or `if(GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0` will not do what you want because it will be fulfilled if any of the bits in the return value are set.

Comment: i'm using `GetAsyncKeyState`  inside a function that takes a lot of time and when i use    (GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000) it didn't work @CherryDT

Comment: OK so you do want to keep using the "was pressed since last checked?" feature, but just have a way to clear this buffered state? In this case it's as I said above: calling the function for this key implicitly clears the buffer.